# winappdbg: using a kernel32 function

Tags: python, windows

I try to use the function GetProcessTimes(hprocess).

I use this code :

```
p = debug.excel(argv,bFollow=True)
win32.kernel32.GetProcessTimes(p)
```

But that does not work ...

> this function takes 4 arguments (5 given)

Someone could help ? What do I forget ?

Thanks

Comment: *"What do I forget?"* - Three arguments? ;)

Comment: No it's not. GetProcessTimes() take only one ... The error is in kernel32.py ...

Comment: My witty comment was meant to say that unless you post some more detailed information it will be difficult to help you out. For example: are you positive the error is thrown by `GetProcessTimes()`?

Comment: No the error is thrown by _GetProcessTimes() in kernel32.py. I use wrong the API but I dont find any example with this function ..

Answer (score 0):

Can i suggest to do your own call ? (Taken from python [pybench](http://svn.python.org/projects/python/trunk/Tools/pybench/systimes.py) itself):

```
# if you have win32 process
import win32process
def getprocesstimes_systimes():
    d = win32process.GetProcessTimes(win32process.GetCurrentProcess())
    return (d['UserTime'] / WIN32_PROCESS_TIMES_TICKS_PER_SECOND,
        d['KernelTime'] / WIN32_PROCESS_TIMES_TICKS_PER_SECOND)

# otherwise, ctypes approach
import ctypes
def getprocesstimes_systimes():
    creationtime = ctypes.c_ulonglong()
    exittime = ctypes.c_ulonglong()
    kerneltime = ctypes.c_ulonglong()
    usertime = ctypes.c_ulonglong()
    rc = ctypes.windll.kernel32.GetProcessTimes(
        ctypes.windll.kernel32.GetCurrentProcess(),
        ctypes.byref(creationtime),
        ctypes.byref(exittime),
        ctypes.byref(kerneltime),
        ctypes.byref(usertime))
    if not rc:
        raise TypeError('GetProcessTimes() returned an error')
    return (usertime.value / WIN32_PROCESS_TIMES_TICKS_PER_SECOND,
            kerneltime.value / WIN32_PROCESS_TIMES_TICKS_PER_SECOND)
```